# 連想配列で次の要素の値と比較

Tags: php

```
$arr = ['foo' => 10, 'bar' => 11, 'bazz' => 3, 'fizz' => 8];
```

といった連想配列で次の要素の値と比較して小さければfalseを返したいです

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.
`bool is_stairs(array $arg)`

```
<?php
function get_numeric($value)
{
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
    return $value + 0;
}

function is_stairs(array $arg)
{
    if (!$arg) {
        return false;
    }
    $stack = array_values($arg);
    $previ = array_shift($stack);
    $previ = get_numeric($previ);
    foreach ($stack as $value) {
        $value = get_numeric($value);
        if ($value < $previ) {
            return false;
        }
        $previ = $value;
    }
    return true;
}
```

普通の配列にも対応してます。
空配列では `false` が返り、1要素では `true` が返ります。
同じ値が続いた場合でも `false` は返りません。
値に `is_numeric` が `false` を返す要素が含まれていた場合 `InvalidArgumentException` が発行されます。
確かめていませんが、たぶん浮動小数点数でも動作します。

```
<?php
// 空配列: bool(false)
var_dump(is_stairs([]));

// １要素: bool(true)
var_dump(is_stairs([7]));

// bool(true)
var_dump(is_stairs([7, 42]));

// 例: bool(false)
$arr = ['foo' => 10, 'bar' => 11, 'bazz' => 3, 'fizz' => 8];
var_dump(is_stairs($arr));

// bool(true)
$arr = ['foo' => 0, 'bar' => 1, 'bazz' => 3, 'fizz' => 8];
var_dump(is_stairs($arr));

// bool(true)
$arr = ['foo' => 10, 'bar' => 11, 'bazz' => 13, 'fizz' => 18];
var_dump(is_stairs($arr));

// bool(true)
$arr = ['foo' => -INF, 'bar' => -11, 'bazz' => 3, 'fizz' => 8];
var_dump(is_stairs($arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr = ['foo' => 10, 'bar' => 11, 'bazz' => 3, 'fizz' => 8];
//添え字一覧を取得
$keys=array_keys($arr);
//現在の添え字の順番でループ
for($n=0,$l=count($keys);($n+1)<$l;$n++){
    //次の添え字と比較し小さければ
    if($arr[$keys[$n]]<$arr[$keys[$n+1]]){
        //false表示
        echo "{$keys[$n]} < {$keys[$n+1]} : is false".nl2br(PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```